# Верстка расположения фотографий

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как можно сверстать,если учитывать что в каждой ячейке находится фото.Если есть пример приведите пожалуйста. Накиньте на идею пожалуйста!(не пользуясь таблицами)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sorx00/Z6dVF/

```
div { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid red; float: left; margin: 1px; padding: 0; }
div.big { width: 104px; height: 104px; }
div.container { border: 1px solid blue; width: 162px; height: 162px; }

<div class="container">
    ​<div class="big"​​​​​​​​​​></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>​​​​​
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!Очень Помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте разбить на 2 блока.Нижний(clear:both)-с горизонтально разположеными картинками через float:left.
В верхнем пропиши картинкам float:right+clear:both и этому контейнеру задай высоту либо overflow:hidden